# Jquery - get "defined" height of an element

Tags: jquery

In the code, the element (tr) has a an inline style tag which defines a height of 31px.
But after rendering, the height of the tr expands to 32px, because of the content.

I'm trying to get read the height of 31px via Jquery, but with these [methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/) I only get the computed height of 32px.

My question is: Do I have to read the style attribute and extract the height from there, or is there another way getting this value using Jquery (or native javascript).

Comment: You have an inline style? or have you defined the style in css

Comment: It's an inline style, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .height

```
trHeight = document.getElementById("myTr").style.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store that height value in a variable and use it wherever you want

Example :-

```
var height = $('tr').css('height'); //This will return the original value
```

Comment: Before I can store it, I need to retrieve it. And the question is if there's a better way to get the value but parsing the style string.

Answer (score 0):

`.css(prop)` is the method in jQuery which behaves as a getter of css styles:

```js
$('pre').append('.css("height")===='+$('button').css('height') +'<<<<<<:::::>>>>>.height()====='+$('button').height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
<button style='height:80px;'>Test</button>
```

Above you can see `.css('height')` returns the actual height set but `.height()` has different calculation.

Comment: Well in this example snippet you can see button has a height of `80px` set by inline style and it returns just that.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I can't run the snippe here. I've tested css.height() and It returned the computed height - that's why I was asking here. Try to put some line breaks to the button text so that the button exceeds the height of 80px, css.height should return then this value.